# Android Studio on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, software-installation

I'd like to use my Raspberry Pi for programming, among others, Java. As an editor, I would like to use Android Studio.

Is there a kind of Android Studio to install on the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really feasible; although Studio (and the community version of IntelliJ, around which it is built) and the SDK are open source<sup>1</sup>, I do not think anyone would bother compiling it for ARM systems since these are generally small like the Raspberry Pi.

The [download page](https://developer.android.com/studio/) states 3 GB of RAM as a minimum and recommends 8, which obviously rules out the Pi. Just loading a project in Studio here (on an x86-64 linux system) sucks ~1 1/4 GB immediately, and it is doubtless relying on shared libraries that are already loaded and part of the ~3.5 GB already occupied.

However, `adb` is available in Raspbian, as is gradle.  With sufficient knowledge of the build system you probably could put a development environment together, but you could not use something as hefty as Studio.

---

1. Actually the SDK is probably not really "open source" in a strict sense, but the source code is publicly available.

Comment: Raspberry pi 4 comes with 8GB RAM by <2020.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/8gb-raspberry-pi-4-on-sale-now-at-75/